# Equivalent of grep string matching to sed & awk

Tags: awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching, hex

I am currently processing large files looking for unmatched patterns. I am using grep to achieve this. And for some reason, grep ignores/excludes some of the potential unmatched patterns. Both the pattern and string files consist of hexadecimal characters. There are around 200k patterns each ranging anywhere between 12 and 500 characters and 13k strings that are each 2,880,560 characters long. I am using the following command:

```
grep -oFf patterns.txt large_strings.txt | grep -vFf - patterns.txt > unmatched_patterns.txt
```

The above command first extracts all the matched patterns and then saves the unmatched patterns from the matched patterns into a text file. Is there an equivalent sed or awk command that imitates this task? I tried the above mentioned grep command using two different machines (my personal machine and cluster) and the results are the same.

I ran `getconf ARG_MAX` and got the following output for the cluster:

```
4611686018427387903
```

Examples of some of the unmatched patterns are as follows:

```
fffbfefffffefffffffffffefffffffffffefffffffffffefffffffffffefffffffffffefffffffffffefffffffffffefffffefffffefffffefffffefffffefffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffeffffffffffffffff
1d2a0e1d2a101c290f1b280e1a270d18250b17240a17230b16220a16220a15210915210916220a16220c19220d1b230e1b230e1b230e1c240d1c240d1c240d1c240d1b250c1c260d1c26
fefffffefffffffffffffffffffdfffffffffffdfeff
```

A samples file of large strings consisting of two strings can be found in the link below:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/b1plp74uztkicyr/large_strings.txt/file

Comment: Can you a sample of an "unmatched pattern"?

Comment: I have supplied some example of unmatched patterns.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output (no links, no images, not just descriptions) then we can help you.

Comment: [I see](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/365811/user3441801) you've never accepted an answer to any of your questions, as advised in the comments above please read https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

Using `awk`, read all patterns into an associative array as keys.  Then go though the lines in the data file one by one, and for each line, test each remaining pattern against it.  If a pattern matches, remove that from the associative array.

At the end, output the patterns that remain unmatched.

```c
NR == FNR { pat[$0] = 1; next }

{
    for (p in pat)
        if (index($0,p) != 0)
            delete pat[p]
}

END {
    for (p in pat)
        print p
}
```

You would save this into a file, e.g. `script.awk`, and then run with

```
awk -f script.awk patterns.txt large_strings.txt >unmatched_patterns.txt
```

This will perform string comparisons using `index()`, not regular expression matches (just as with `grep -F`), but will potentially match multiple pattern strings at overlapping locations in the data, which I don't think `grep` would do (the patterns `ab` and `ba` would both match the data `aba`).

Testing on dummy data:

```
$ cat patterns.txt
a
b
c
d
```

```
$ cat strings.txt
abba
bull
cooler
```

```
$ awk -f script.awk patterns.txt strings.txt
d
```

(The string `d` is not found in the `strings.txt` file.)

Comment: the awk script is still processing and is way slower than grep :(

Comment: @user3441801 you posted this question because what you're doing with grep doesn't produce the output you expect. We can come up with faster awk solutions if speed of execution is more important than getting exactly the output you expect. The point is it makes no sense to compare execution speed of something that works against something that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `grep`, I'd do instead:

```
(
  export LC_ALL=C
  sort -uo patterns.txt patterns.txt # if not already uniqued and sorted in the C locale
  grep -oFf patterns.txt large_strings.txt |
    sort -u |
    comm -13 - patterns.txt > unmatched_patterns
)
```

In theory, it should be slower than @Kusalananda's answer in that it looks for *all* occurrences of the patterns.

Comment: Is writing `sort` output to its input file guaranteed to succeed?

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, that's the reason why `sort` has a `-o` option in the first place (it needs to read its input fully before it starts outputting anything, so `-o` is there so that that output can go to the same file as the input comes from). [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sort.html) makes it explicit that the output file *may be the same as any of the input files*.